# (SQL) Select and return all from more than 2 tables that have a common field where a specific value is present in all tables

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access

As above, I would like the result to be one row of all the columns from each table where the value was met. The common field in all tables is the primary key. Any type of UNION does not work as the amount of columns is not the same in each table. I'm using an Access database so FULL OUTER JOINS are not supported. I'm using this query in an application in C#, Visual Studio and for some reason can't get do an inner join without it giving me a syntax error either. I'd ideally like to have this done in one query.

For example lets say I have the tables:

**Table1**

```
userID  name  age
1       Bob   24
2       John  19
```

**Table2**

```
userID  col1  col2  col3
1       fd    sd    gh
...
```

**Table3**

```
userID  col4  col5  col6  col7
1       ff    hg    fd    et
...
```

**And I want the result:**

`userID  name  age  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
 1       Bob   24   fd    sd    gh    ff    hg    fd    et`

**Perhaps the closest I've got:**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS b
INNER JOIN table2 AS c ON c.userID = b.userID
INNER JOIN table3 AS m ON m.userID = b.userID 
WHERE userID = 1;
```

**The error I get:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query
>   expression 'c.userID = b.userID INNER JOIN table3 AS m ON
>   m.userID = b.UserI'.

I should add that I want the query to be adaptable (let's say I don't know the columns but I know it has userID)

Comment: Can you please post the query you wrote, and the error you are getting please?

Comment: use `Inner join `

Comment: I'm trying to, see my attempt above

Comment: Is this your real query or are you simplifying your query? If you are simplifying could you please post your real query? I suspect that you have just a simple syntax error

Comment: Are any of the table/column names 2 words e.g. user id? If that is the case you would need to have square brackets [ ] around the words. e.g. [user id]

Comment: I'm just changing the names from my real query, it is the exact same structure. I would suspect that too but I honestly don't have a syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I was close.

In MS-Access, when joining more than 2 tables you must use parentheses (around the first join?). Second of all, in my where condition I didn't specify a table for userID. See my amended query below:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS b
(INNER JOIN table2 AS c ON c.userID = b.userID)
INNER JOIN table3 AS m ON m.userID = b.userID 
WHERE b.userID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Left joins should work in ms-access:

```
select *
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2
    on t1.userID = t2.userID
left join Table3 t3
    on t1.userID = t3.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Acces:

```
Select T1.userID, T1.name,  T1.age, T2.col1,  T2.col2,  T2.col3, T3.col4,  T3.col5, T3.col6,  T3.col7 from Table1 T1
left join Table2 T2 on T2.userID=T1.userID
left join Table3 T3 on T3.userID=T1.userID
```

Or if you only want records present in the first table use an inner join:

```
 Select T1.userID, T1.name,  T1.age, T2.col1,  T2.col2,  T2.col3, T3.col4,  T3.col5, T3.col6,  T3.col7 from Table1 T1
    inner join Table2 T2 on T2.userID=T1.userID
    inner join Table3 T3 on T3.userID=T1.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
t1.userID 
,t1.name
,tb1.age
,tb2.col1
,tb2.col2
,tb2.col3
,tb3.col4
,tb3.col5
,tb3.col6
,tb3.col7
FROM table1 tb1
INNER JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb1.userID=tb2.userID
INNER JOIN table3 tb3 ON tb1.userID=tb3.userID
WHERE --some conditions if u desire.
```

Comment: I'm really working with a lot more tables, which will have slight changes in the future. So a hard-coded solution will not do unfortunately as I want it to be adaptable

Comment: If you dont want to select specific column tables just make a select all and then, if you want information to come from the first table u declare, make an inner join otherwise a left join, in case you want the information from the tables you joined.
So, i would replace in the query i show to you: SELECT * from table1; and replace the inner join for left join

Comment: Your suggestion returned the same error as above, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem in where condition.you did not specify the table.

So change.

```
Where userId=1
```

To be

```
Where b.userId=1
```